# Autolayout - Adjust Label Y position on the basis of other label's dynamic height above it

Tags: ios, autolayout, xcode9, swift3.2

I have two labels. Label A and Label B as shown below.

[View with both labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NwG7.png)

[View when Label A height is 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiABs.png)

I want to move Label B up with top margin to superview = 20pt, when Label A height is zero.

If label A height is > 0 Then Label B Y position is = 
Label A top Margin + Label A height + Vertical Spacing between Label A and B. (i.e. Bottom Of Label A + Vertical Spacing b/w Label A and B = Label B Y postion)
Is it possible to do it using autolayout?

Comment: Where is the question.. No one knows which label you want to adjust -_-
Assuming A is dynamic and you want B to move down..
Make Label A have a `contentHuggingPriority` of `.required` and `contentCompressionResistancePriority` of `.required`.. Then the top label will size itself to fit and the other one will move accordingly.

Comment: I want to move Label B up when Label A height is zero. If Label A height is zero I want to remove vertical spacing

Comment: User a UIStackView..

Comment: Use a `UIStackView` with axis set to vertical. Use spacing of 20, alignment fill, distribution fill. Now you have to adjust the hugging priority -> set lower value for whichever label needs to grow more than the other.

Comment: Whenever you need to set the height of the label A to `0`, you would only need to set the `hidden` property of that label to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

You can have all constraints for the **LabelA.height > 0** case linked to a **NSLayoutConstraint IBOutletCollection**.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) *labelAScenarioConstraints;`

Same for the LabelA.height = 0 scenario like

`@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutletCollection(NSLayoutConstraint) *labelAWithoutHeightScenarioConstraints`

And when you want to change it just do something like:

```
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in labelAScenarioConstraints) {
    [constraint setActive:labelA.frame.size.height > 0];
}
for (NSLayoutConstraint *constraint in labelAWithoutHeightScenarioConstraints) {
    [constraint setActive:labelA.frame.size.height == 0];
}
```

You can activate or deactivate a constraint by changing this property...Activating or deactivating the constraint calls addConstraint: and removeConstraint: on the view that is the closest common ancestor of the items managed by this constraint. Use this property instead of calling addConstraint: or removeConstraint: directly.

Keep in mind that all the UI updates should be done from the main thread. If you want to animate the constraints change you can put the code inside **UIView animateWithDuration** animations block.